# Ignore file from git commit but protect it from clean

Tags: git, gitignore

In my work tree I have a mixture of files in .gitignore:

1. Build outputs
2. Sensitive files that shouldn't be part of the repo (e.g. passwords, connection details for local servers)

If I want to rebuild my project from scratch, I can do `git clean -x` to remove the build outputs in (1). But this also removes the sensitive files in (2).

Is there a way to mark a file so it's not affected by `git clean` while still being ignored by `git commit`?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to mark the file, you'll need to explicitly exclude it when running the clean command: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085795/git-exclude-a-file-with-git-clean

Comment: GNU Arch used to (well, it still does, but nobody uses it any more) distinguish between “junk” and “precious” files for precisely this purpose. Unfortunately, no other version control system added that distinction.

Comment: How about -X option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The documentation for [`git-clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) says:

> `-x`
>
> > Don’t use the standard ignore rules read from .gitignore (per directory) and  $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, but do still use the ignore rules given with -e options.

and:

> `-e <pattern>`, `--exclude=<pattern>`
>
> > Use the given exclude pattern in addition to the standard ignore rules (see gitignore(5)).

So if you want to keep, say, `keys.pem`, you would call

```
git clean -fdxe keys.pem
```

You can also create [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) for the command.

Comment: This is nice... in my case, the files I want to keep happen to match a single pattern, so I have:
`git clean -nxd -e ".*"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `git clean` in **[*Interactive mode*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#_interactive_mode)**:

choose [*filter by pattern*](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean#git-clean-filterbypattern) subcommand:

> This shows the files and directories to be deleted and issues an
>   "Input ignore patterns>>" prompt. **You can input space-separated
>   patterns to exclude files and directories from deletion.** E.g. "*.c
>   *.h" will excludes files end with ".c" and ".h" from deletion. When you are satisfied with the filtered result, press ENTER (empty) back
>   to the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

Take a [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/65004) from [@Borealid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/65004) to the question [Git - Difference Between 'assume-unchanged' and 'skip-worktree'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13630849/git-difference-between-assume-unchanged-and-skip-worktree/13631525#13631525).

It looks like using the `skip-worktree` flag is a good way to solve my problem.  I got to your problem by looking for an answer to my problem, and I think they are essentially the same problem.  However, using the `skip-worktree` flag, *you still need to pay attention when performing certain operations and the file has changed either locally or on the remote*.

Prior to learning about the `skip-worktree` flag, the best solution I could come up with is to use a combination of `.gitignore` plus an alias for `git clean`.  It is a bit of a hack, but if your only option is to use the exclude option with `git clean`, then this may help.

1. Add a consistent and unique prefix and/or postfix to any files you are modifying and do not want to commit.  For example, add `myusername.` to the beginning of the filename.
2. Always use `git clean -dx --exclude=myusername.*` (make an alias for this).
3. Write a script that recursively walks your files and copies files beginning with `myusername.` to files without `myusername.`.

Now, whenever you run cleanup, the files with the desired/true filename **are** going to get cleaned, **but** you can restore them by running the script.  Also, treat the files with the true filename as readonly.  Always edit the files with the kludged filenames and then run the script.

Combining these might also work to mitigate the edge cases when using the `skip-worktree` flag.