# My interpreter has been deleted by command 'git clean -d -f'

Tags: python, git, gitlab

My python interpreter setting been deleted by this `git clean  -d  -f` so now do i have to reinstall all package requirements?. Is there any way i can undo this.

I was trying to remove _ _ pychache _ _ files. but by mistake typed this `git clean  -d  -f` command.

if I had to install all packages again then i would be in big trouble cause of high chances of mismatch module version

Comment: I'm guessing your question is whether it is possible to undo git clean, so there is this duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267180/can-i-restore-deleted-files-undo-a-git-clean-fdx

Comment: what do you mean by your interpreter setting?

Answer (score 1):

If the file was private, meaning not added to the index through git add, and not committed, then double-check your editor/IDE: it might still have a local history for that file.

If not, then you need to use a file recovery utility, as detailed in "[Can I restore deleted files (undo a `git clean -fdx`)?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42861993/6309)".

It is best to have an [alias for `git clean`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43681033/6309), in order to delete the (.gitignore'd) `__pycache__` while keeping the (.gitignore'd) [`.iml`/`.idea` project setting files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-projects.html#directory-based) you want to keep during a clean (even an inadvertent one)