# How to keep lost+found directory in git?

Tags: git

My git project is on a separate `ext4` partition, which contains
`lost+found` directory.

It is deleted by `git clean -d`.

If I try to add it to git, it says

```
error: pathspec 'lost+found' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

If I add it to `.gitignore`, it is deleted by `git clean -X -d`

So, how do I say `git` to leave it alone?

(None of the solutions in [Git: Exclude a file with git clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085795/git-exclude-a-file-with-git-clean) works here)

Comment: @Vanna No, there is no solution for this in that post.

Comment: Git wouldn't delete anything that isn't under its control.  Are you saying you've got the *entire* partition under version control?

Comment: @Makoto yes, the project is on a dedicated partition

Comment: Note: regarding `git clean -d`, this has evolved with Git 2.14: see "[`git clean` removes ignored files by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44351432/6309)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is an empty folder, try and add a placeholder file instead:

```
cd /path/to/git/repo
touch lost+found/.gitkeep
git add lost+found/.gitkeep
```

Then a `git clean -d` would not delete that folder (since it includes tracked content)

Note: if you are sure you won't have to track anything in that folder, you can replace `.gitkeep` by a `.gitignore` (inside the `lost+found` folder, that you might have to create first with [`mklost+found`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mklost+found), depending on your file system).
The content of that `.gitignore` would then be '`*`' (without the simple quotes). Source: [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538735/how-to-keep-lostfound-directory-in-git/45539576?noredirect=1#comment78059214_45539576).

Comment: Note that if the directory is deleted, Git will recreate it with `mkdir()` instead of with `mklost+found`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp so one should do a mklost+found first?

Comment: @VonC I don't know about modern Linux but "back in the day" when the BSD `fsck` needed to put files into `lost+found`, it needed the directory to have a bunch of empty slots, so that there were already known-good (because all checked by that point) disk blocks available so that the directory did not have to be expanded in size, in order to add entries to it. That's what `mklost+found` did. BSD's UFS/UFS2 `fsck` is now much fancier and can create and grow the `lost+found` directory if needed. ZFS doesn't need it, being very different in design.

Comment: @torek OK. Not sure what is the OP environment here, but I'll keep hat in mind.

Comment: On an unrelated side note, I like to use a possibly-empty `.gitignore` rather than a `.gitkeep`. Here, I'd use a `.gitignore` containing `*`.

Comment: @torek I initially chose gitkeep because I wasn't sure the OP wanted to eventually track files in that folder or not.

Comment: @torek Still, I have included your suggestion (about `.gitignore`) in the answer for more visibility.