# Git: Exclude some files when ran git clean

Tags: git

I want to clean up files which ignored by .gitignore, but I want to exclude some files specified by excluding options.
And then, I don't want to remove untracked files.

```
dist                     (ignored)
node_modules             (ignored)
.env                     (ignored but I want to exclude for the cleanup)
I_do_not_want_add_yet.js (untracked, I don't want cleanup some untracked files)
package.json             (There are many other tracked files)
```

So I looked into [some posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085795/git-exclude-a-file-with-git-clean) and tried the following command:

```sh
$ git clean -ndX -e .env
Would remove dist/
Would remove node_modules/
Would remove .env   # Oops!

$ git clean -ndX --exclude='!.env'
Would remove dist/
Would remove node_modules/
Would remove .env   # Oops!

$ git clean -ndx -e .env
Would remove dist/
Would remove node_modules/
Would remove I_do_not_want_add_yet.js   # Oops!
```

Do you have good ideas?

Comment: Given that the main purpose of git-clean is to do the literal opposite of what you want, I'm not sure it's the right tool to begin with.

Comment: You can use `git status --ignored`, then filter out the files you want to keep from that before deleting.

Comment: Awesome! I got a good hint from what you said. Its command is helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could solve using the command, which is a little hacky:

```sh
git ls-files --other --ignored --exclude-standard \
  | grep -v -E "^\.env" \
  | xargs -I{} rm -rf {}
```